# 1: my spider is giving me all the results in one liners on csv file

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

In the first place, If I use extract_first, scrapy gives me the first element of each page and if I run it like this it returns all the content I want but in one-liners.

In Second place, I can't make scrapy go to the links I just scraped and get information from inside these links, returning an empty csv file.

```
from scrapy import Spider
from companies.items import CompaniesItem
import re

class companiesSpider(Spider):
    name = "companies"
    allowed_domains = ['http://startup.miami',]
    # Defining the list of pages to scrape
    start_urls = ["http://startup.miami/category/startups/page/" + str(1*i) + "/" for i in range(0, 10)]

    def parse(self, response):
        rows = response.xpath('//*[@id="datafetch"]')

        for row in rows: 
            link = row.xpath('.//h2/a/@href').extract()

            name = row.xpath('.//header/h2/a/text()').extract()


            item = CompaniesItem()
            item['link'] = link
            item['name'] = name

            yield item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parse-method is not yielding any requests or items. In the part below we go through the pages and get the urls & names. In the parse_detail you can add additional data to the item.
Instead of hardcoding to 10 pages we check if there is a next page, and go through the parse again if it's the case.

```
from scrapy import Spider
from ..items import CompaniesItem
import scrapy


class CompaniesSpider(Spider):
    name = "companies"
    allowed_domains = ['startup.miami']
    # Defining the list of pages to scrape
    start_urls = ["http://startup.miami/category/startups/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        # get link & name and send item to parse_detail in meta
        rows = response.xpath('//*[@id="datafetch"]/article')
        for row in rows:
            link = row.xpath('.//@href').extract_first()
            name = row.xpath(
                './/*[@class="textoCoworking"]/text()').extract_first()
            item = CompaniesItem()
            item['link'] = link
            item['name'] = name.strip()
            yield scrapy.Request(link,
                                 callback=self.parse_detail,
                                 meta={'item': item})
        # get the next page
        next_page = response.xpath(
            '//*[@class="next page-numbers"]/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_detail(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        # add other details to the item here
        yield item
```

To put the results in a csv file you can launch the scraper like this: `scrapy crawl companies -o test_companies.csv`

Comment: Thank you Wim, unfortunately, this didn't work. Also, I need to get the information inside the links I'm trying to scrape

Comment: There were quite some issues with the code I posted - edited and tested now, should work better.

Comment: Try to run it like this: `scrapy crawl companies -s LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG -o test_companies.csv` and see if you get correct responses back for the requests.

Comment: Genius! That worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your help!